# Trigger Pipeline B on Monthly schedule and when Pipeline A is completed

Tags: triggers, scheduled-tasks, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I have an import pipeline (Pipeline A) that runs every 2 hours, it imports the Data from local SQL DBs up into my Azure DB.

Part of this data is used with integration into a 3rd party system (that is updated every 2 hours) the other parts of this data are used for Reporting.

I have a Monthly Report Pipeline (Pipeline B) that does the following:

Executes Stored Procedures, Outputs the results to a Blob, then triggers a Logic App to upload the contents of the Blob to the destination.

However, If Pipeline B is triggered whilst Pipeline A is running, then there will be errors.

I would like to create a Monthly trigger for Pipeline B, but make it so that it is only ever run after Pipeline A  first completes on the first day of the Month.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can excute the Pipeline A manually in the PipielineB.

[image]

1. trigger Pipeline_B_A run monthly.
2. trigger Pipeline_A run every 2 hours.

Comment: Cool - took a moment to figure out what needed to be done - but yes - setting both pipelines to run in the Monthly task should work